# Where are chromium extensions located?

Tags: chromium, extension

Where are extensions stored once they've been installed to Chromium?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Extensions are ([usually](https://askubuntu.com/a/445301/8515)) stored at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions`. Here's an example featuring the amazing [adblock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom):

```
jake@daedalus:~$ cd .config/chromium/Default/Extensions/
jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions$ ls
gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/  jggheggpdocamneaacmfoipeehedigia/
jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions$ cd gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/2.3.1_0/
jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/2.3.1_0$ ls
adblock.js        background.html  blacklisting/         button/     functions.js  img/        jquery/    manifest.json  pages/   whitelister.js
adblock_start.js  blacklister.js   broadcast_channel.js  filtering/  Icon.png      Info.plist  _locales/  options/       port.js
```

To see it in your file browser, make sure you can see hidden files (View > Show Hidden Files). Or, do like Gaurav says and type in the path after pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This path answered for me:
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions

Answer (score 11):

While the usual profile path for Chromium-based browser is in `~/.config/chromium/<name of profile>`

This is wrong if you under these circumstances:

- have multiple users in Chromium
- specified the user profile path in Chromium
- config folder is different if you're using app containers (snap/Flatpak/AppImage).

Visit `chrome://version/` in your Chrome and check "Profile Path" for the definitive answer.

Comment: Like above answer, in my case, extension located at '~/.config/chromium/Profile 1' , '~/.config/chromium/Profile 2  ' '~/.config/chromium/Profile 3'  and '~/.config/chromium/Profile 4'

Comment: This should be best answer. Chromium was installed with snap for me so was in a much different place. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Type this in  Nautilus after pressing "ctrl+L"

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
```

Comment: won't work because not everyone's user name is gaurav.

Answer (score 4):

They are located in:

`/home/USER_NAME/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/`

Where USER_NAME is your user name.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Google chrome then look in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions`

Answer (score 2):

On the filesystem? In `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions` (a hidden folder inside your home directory).

Answer (score 2):

It also can be in

```
/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings
```

verify where is installed path.

```
chrome://version/
```